# Angular ng-repeat not showing on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've never had this issue before, but I've got an Angular controller that pulls a list of client connection data from a SignalR HUB and displays it on a status page.  It's pretty straightforward stuff.

My problem is: when the page is loaded, the controller runs and it retrieves the data properly, but it won't show on page until I do something that "jostles" angular, like clicking in the filter text box and then clicking out of it.  I don't actually have to do anything that changes data.  I've set a breakpoint and verified that the data is loaded properly, and it is being assigned to the scope.  I also tried using a $scope.$apply() right after the data load, but it didn't have any impact.  Here is the relevent code:

Controller:

```
angular.module('statusModule', ['utilitiesModule']).
    controller('statusController', ['$scope', '$location', 'Util',
    function ($scope, $location, Util) {

        var gurcaHub = $.connection.gurcaHub;
        var indexes = {};
        var clients = [];
        $scope.search = { domain: '' };

        var refreshClientList = function () {
            gurcaHub.server.getClients("", 0).done(function (result) {
                angular.forEach(result, function (item) {

                    // omitted for brevity, all this does is massage the data a bit 

                    clients.push(item);

                });
                $scope.clients = clients;
            });
        };


        angular.element(document).ready(function () {

            $.connection.hub.error(function (error) {
                $scope.errorMsg = error;
            });

            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                gurcaHub.server.connectManager({ ManagerToken: "123" }).done(function () {
                    refreshClientList();
                });
            });

        });

    }]);
```

And here is the relevent HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="item in clients | filter:search">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">{{item.domain}} <span class="badge">{{item.numClients}}</span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Machine Name</th>
                        <th>Client ID</th>
                        <th>IP</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="client in item.clientList">
                        <td>{{client.Type}}</td>
                        <td>{{client.MachineName}}</td>
                        <td>{{client.ClientId}}</td>
                        <td>{{client.Ip}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>            
        </div>
    </div>
```

I did remove the filter and I still have the same problem.  Again, all I have to do is click in a form input field and then de-focus it again and everything shows up.  I don't have to type anything.  The data is there, it's just not displayed until you do something.

Comment: Did you try including `$scope.clients = [];` where you declared variables? That way, the model is available at DOM creation.

Comment: @kubuntu Good suggestion,  but it didn't change anything. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment (`$scope.clients = clients;`) after `angular.forEach` executes before the loop is completed.

Try

```
....
    function ($scope, $location, $q, Util) {
    ...

        var refreshClientList = function () {
            gurcaHub.server.getClients("", 0).done(function (result) {
                angular.forEach(result, function (item) {

                    // omitted for brevity, all this does is massage the data a bit 

                    clients.push(item);

                });
                // execute when done processing
                $q.all(clients).then(function(){
                    $scope.clients = clients;
                });

            });
        };
...

}]);
```

Comment: Where did you read that `angular.forEach` is async? As far as I know, `forEach` from Angular is synchronous.

Comment: This did the trick!  I've never seen $q before, I'll need to research what it does.